# Show that $\sup \{f(x) + g(x) : x \in\ X\} \leq \sup \{f(x) : x \in\ X\} + \sup \{g(x) : x \in\ X\}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, and let $f$ and $g$ be defined on $X$ and ave bounded ranges in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that:

$$\sup \{f(x) + g(x) : x \in\ X\} \leq \sup \{f(x) : x \in\ X\} + \sup \{g(x) : x \in\ X\}$$

Comment: $f+g\leq \sup f +\sup g$ and then take $\inf$ on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{gathered}
  f\left( x \right) + g\left( x \right) \leqslant \sup \left\{ {f\left( x \right):x \in X} \right\} + \sup \left\{ {g\left( x \right):x \in X} \right\},\,\,\forall x \in X \hfill \\
   \Rightarrow \sup \left\{ {f\left( x \right) + g\left( x \right):x \in X} \right\} \leqslant \sup \left\{ {f\left( x \right):x \in X} \right\} + \sup \left\{ {g\left( x \right):x \in X} \right\} \hfill \\
   \Rightarrow \inf \left\{ {f\left( x \right) + g\left( x \right):x \in X} \right\} \leqslant \sup \left\{ {f\left( x \right):x \in X} \right\} + \sup \left\{ {g\left( x \right):x \in X} \right\} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$